# Dynamics ax 2009: How to close form on a different user?

Tags: winapi, axapta, x++

I am looking for a some way to close a one from all active **form** from a different user, something like as a function terminate.

```
SysClientSessions sys;
xSession ses
;

select firstonly sys where sys.UserId == 'some user';
ses = new xSession( sys.SessionId );
ses.terminate(); // in here client of 'some user' will be closed
```

Comment: Not sure if you can directly influence a different user session like this, but a different idea might be to customize `SysSetupFormRun` class to check continuously e.g. in a new table for an entry (e.g. fields `UserId` and `FormName`) and if an entry is found, the form closes itself. You might want to give the user a warning with a timeout.

Comment: this example is working. In SysSetupFormRun can i check if user have runned a form and doing nothing?

Comment: AX has an option to terminate a session after the session has been idle a certain time ([How to set up auto log out in Microsoft Dynamics AX](http://msdynamicsaxtips.blogspot.de/2014/07/is-it-possible-to-kill-ax-user-session.html)). I haven't looked into it, but maybe there is something that you can use to detect idleness for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the user's form `hWnd` you can close it via:

`WinAPI::sendMessageEx(hWnd, #WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);`

So you need to come up with a method of obtaining user's forms. You could do something similar to this:

http://sinedax.blogspot.com/2015/12/ax-2012-close-open-forms.html

Comment: How to get handle (hwnd) of diffrent user form? Second winapi have to been run on client site, is possible to send command from server to client to do something?

Comment: The link proposes that all window handles are stored in the global cache by modifying the `SysSetupFormRun` class. But I don't think a `WinAPI` call will work for a window running on another client which may run on a different machine.

Comment: I think you would have to do one of two things. Either the clients would actively check to see if they need to close windows or you would have to send an event to the clients to trigger that action. The `EventInbox` stuff would probably make the most sense to somehow hook into, just because it already has polling and things setup. It seems like there is no 1-line solution that you were hoping for.